# How to delete evicted pods that are older than a month

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to delete Kubernetes evicted pods which are older than 30 days from all namespaces, but the command throws an error :

```
Error from server(NotFound): pods (xxxxxxxxxxxxx) not found
```

Command:

```
kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  | grep Evicted | sed 's#d$##' | awk '$6 > 30 {print $2}')"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought when I read "evicted pods" was https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXZc-6AIRhs (although that scene is not _quite_ how I remember it ...)

Comment: whats the output of  `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  | grep Evicted | sed 's#d$##' | awk '$6 > 30 {print $2}'` ?

Answer (score 2):

This assumes the GNU coreutils version of `date` and a bourne-like shell:

One-liner:

```bash
onemonthago=$(date -u -d '-1 month' +"%FT%TZ"); kubectl get pod --field-selector='status.phase=Failed' -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.reason,STARTTIME:.status.startTime -A | while read ns pod status starttime; do if [ "$status" = "Evicted" ]; then if [ "$starttime" \< "$onemonthago" ]; then kubectl -n $ns delete pod $pod --wait=false; fi; fi; done
```

More readable formatting:

```bash
onemonthago=$(date -u -d '-1 month' +"%FT%TZ"); 
kubectl get pod --field-selector='status.phase=Failed' -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.reason,STARTTIME:.status.startTime -A | while read ns pod status starttime; do 
    if [ "$status" = "Evicted" ]; then 
        if [ "$starttime" \< "$onemonthago" ]; then 
            kubectl -n $ns delete pod $pod --wait=false; 
        fi; 
    fi; 
done
```

The details:
`onemonthago=$(date -u -d '-1 month' +"%FT%TZ");` gets the cutoff time in the same format as what kubectl returns and stores it in a shell variable.

The kubectl then gets all the failed pods and outputs the columns that we need for further steps.

It then gets piped to a while loop that reads the fields into shell variables.

The `if` statements then check whether the pod was evicted or is failed for another reason (The `status.reason` field is not supported for `--field-selector`) and that it is older than a month. If it matches that criteria, it deletes it.

(It is likely possible to optimise it to gather a list of all pods in a namespace and pass that to the minimum number of kubectls using xargs in one go) (Both checks can be combined, either in the shell or in AWK as well) (Replacing the entire while with an elaborate AWK script would likely yield the best performance (collecting a list of pos to delete per namespace and running / outputting the delete command from the `END` pattern)

Comment: This is great, but surely the comparison should be less than? If start time is less than one month ago, then start time is older. Not the other way around. Otherwise great script!

Comment: @Asu I suspect you are correct - edited

Answer (score 0):

i think it's due to when you are listing down the pod you are listing all pod and deleting all those

but command

`kubectl delete pod` not getting the namespace from which to delete the specific pod

```
kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  | grep Evicted | awk '$6 > 30 {print $2}') -n $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces  | grep Evicted | awk '$6 > 30 {print $1}')
```

maybe you try something like or simplify it better way.

Comment: The certainly deleted evicted pods newer than 30d for me... (I wanted to edit the command to do that anyway, but it might be a problem where someone don't want that) (The cluster is less than a month old and all the evicted pods seems like they were newer than 1 day)

Comment: This also only deletes pods from the first namespace - it passes the rest of the namespaces as pod names to be deleted, resulting in pod not found errors and pods in subsequent namespaces being ignored.